# Why was this simple question so misunderstood?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, vote-to-close

I asked what I thought was a reasonable and simple question:
"[Are there historical examples of "unchartered territory" used correctly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/564686/are-there-historical-examples-of-unchartered-territory-used-correctly/564749#564749).

It received 2 down-votes and 2 votes-to-close, with no explanation.

The only answer it received made no attempt at all to answer the question, yet it got 4 up-votes.

I can't think of any reason why anyone would misunderstand the question, much less why several (between 4 and 8) people would do so.

Can someone explain what happened here?

Comment: Who knows? We aren't psychic. But maybe the fact that you're asking about a very easy thing to mistake turns out to be easily mistaken is the cause? Maybe you could be very explicit and mention the intrusive 'r', and saying explicitly what  the difference in meaning is between 'unchartered'  and 'uncharted'.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I commonly downvote if I see a question that could be answered by anybody with a little effort and no particular skills, knowledge, or expertise: all it took was to google the expression and prune the irrelevant results. That is the only way anyone is likely to answer it, and there is a requirement to do some research before asking, so posting a question is simply lazy. I'm sure the answerer and voters believed they were being helpful, nonetheless.